# This Monday Vs. Next Monday in the following context

Tags: prepositions

Assuming we are on Saturday 29 Jul, and I am talking to my friend about a meeting on Monday 31st Jul 2 days later. If I say to him "Let's meet **this** Monday" is it equal to saying "Let's meet **next** Monday"?

I doubt it because the preposition '**next**' can be related to the last Monday, but on the other hand, it can be related to this Monday, and the meaning would be totally different.

Comment: There is no single answer to this.  In my experience here in the UK, there are regional differences, which would make "next Monday" quite ambiguous for some, but pretty clear for others.  It's probably best to say the actual date to avoid any possible confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In your context, "**let's meet this Monday**" certainly refers to July 31st.

However, "**let's meet next Monday**" might mean either July 31st, or August 7th.  If it were not clear from context which of these were intended, the listener might ask "Do you mean this coming Monday, the 31st, or the Monday after that, the 7th?".